# Does SQL Server 2017 CU1 break clusterless availability groups?

Tags: availability-groups, sql-server-2017

Background:

My division is is doing an upgrade from SQL Server 2008R2 with mirroring to SQL Server 2017 with clusterless availability groups. Until recently the testing has surfaced no issues or red flags. Then we installed CU1, had issues, uninstalled CU1 and the issues went away. The OS is server 2016 with the latest patches.

Observed behavior after CU1:

Using either SSMS or tsql we could create a 2 replica clusterless synchronous availability group, and add one database to it. The group could be failed over multiple times without issue. Ah, but add a second database and issues would arise on the failovers. One of the databases would invariably wind up in a not synchronizing state. No amount of fiddling could resurrect it. If I dropped and recreated the whole thing, it might be the other database that went to not syncing. A pertinent error message in the logger was "Failed to update Replica status due to exception 35222." This seems to be a message related to clusters, but since we are clusterless I was confused. After we uninstalled CU1 on both replicas, I was able to create the AG and add 22 databases (including the two original). Failovers were without issue. On a side note, automatic seeding did not always work with multiple databases. The operation would fail with a "Seeding Check Message Timeout". Dropping those databases from the AG and adding them one at a time was successful.

My question is:

**Has anyone else experienced issues with clusterless AGs after CU1? If so, were you successful where I was not?**

Comment/opinion:

I thought CUs were going to be tested at the same level as SPs. While I know that bugs creep in no matter how thorough the testing, having this happen on the first one is troubling. It will cause us to really stress test each CU before deploying, which will mean we do not deploy them as they come out. We will deploy them only when we think there is a need to. We are a small organization without a dedicated dba, and need to be selective about what take on.

Answer (score 8):

> My division is is doing an upgrade from SQL Server 2008R2 with mirroring to SQL Server 2017 with clusterless availability groups.

So you're upgrading versions but REMOVING high availability and disaster recovery? Clusterless AGs are called "Read-Scale" AGs and do not give high availability and you can argue on the disaster recovery part...

> The group could be failed over multiple times without issue. Ah, but add a second database and issues would arise on the failovers. One of the databases would invariably wind up in a not synchronizing state. No amount of fiddling could resurrect it.

I've been seeing this when a configuration only replica (came in CU1) isn't used with Read-Scale AGs that are being used to fail over. Read-Scale wasn't made to fail over and all that jazz, it was made to horizontally scale out read copies for intense read situations (or as a way to replica across Windows/Linux for migrations). I must reiterate, "clusterless" AGs are not made for HADR. If this is part of your use case, use WSFC or Pacemaker (Linux). [Info on Configuration Only Replica.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-availability-group-ha#two-synchronous-replicas-and-a-configuration-only-replica)

> A pertinent error message in the logger was "Failed to update Replica status due to exception 35222." This seems to be a message related to clusters, but since we are clusterless I was confused.

There should be an error directly before this, that's the actual error you want to look into. This doesn't have anything to do with clustering and is not a clustering error, it's a replica error.

> After we uninstalled CU1 on both replicas, I was able to create the AG and add 22 databases (including the two original). Failovers were without issue

This goes back to pre-configuration only replicas for adding into Read-Scale replicas. Again, surprised you didn't run into a few different issues as Read-Scale isn't made for HADR.

> On a side note, automatic seeding did not always work with multiple databases. The operation would fail with a "Seeding Check Message Timeout".

Seems unrelated, but you never know - could be a side effect of whatever was going on. Impossible to say at this point.

> I thought CUs were going to be tested at the same level as SPs.

You're correct. Changes in behavior between CUs (much like also were involved in SPs) can and do happen given the newer model (even in the SP + CU days this happened). I'd be interested to see if the configuration replica solves your issue since it was specifically added in CU1 for metadata safety as metadata issues for the replicas can and did happen since Read-Scale *again* wasn't made for HADR.

Comment: Great response, Sean. Nice to have a larger MS presence on here this days :)

Comment: In our case(manufacturing), we never did an automatic failover, even with mirroring. We always rely on our backups taken at 10-15 minute intervals as our main fallback. We use mirroring(asysc) to maintain a replica for failover in case of need or maintenance. We are really just trying to recreate that scenario, with the added benefit that the secondaries can be readable now; i.e. nothing automatic except the data being kept in sync. Are you saying that cluster-less AGs will not handle that scenario?

Comment: Also, when I read this documentation, I came away with the distinct impression that read-scale can very much do failover operations. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/perform-a-planned-manual-failover-of-an-availability-group-sql-server#ReadScaleOutOnly

Comment: @JohnH It *can* do a failover, but the intent wasn't to fail over often if ever. Remember that there is nothing other than the transport messages to provide failover synchronization. It was meant for two things, 1) readable replicas (scale out) without a cluster. 2) migration between systems without needing a cluster (such as Windows->Linux). It's not HA and arguably DR... whereas mirroring can be HA and is DR. It's also a 1-1 (primary->mirror) rather than 1 to many with no real quorum or decision factors outside of its own messaging.

Comment: Sean, first of all thank you for your comments, this is new information for us. We still think our use case is a perfect fit for cluster-less AGs, being that we do not fail over much if at all; i.e. it has been over 2 years since the last one. We really want to avoid clusters because we are not staffed for it, so it seemed to us a good fit. I have continued to test without CU1 and have discovered that after a failover all it takes is a reboot of the secondary replicas and they all come back into sync. Now my question...with CU1, what is the configuration only replica for?

Comment: @JohnH It does sound like a pretty good fit, I was basing my comments off of what you already had (mirroring) and letting you know they don't directly translate in abilities. I agree that if you don't need high availability and don't have any problems redirecting your applications through something like a CNAME then this will fit for you. What you've described (the needing of a restart of the services) is what I see and was mentioning in my answer.

Comment: @JohnH This is quite a length comment discussion, however... Configuration replicas are used to store availability group and availability database metadata so that, depending on other options chosen, there may be a chance for data protection and potentially some portion of high availability. Think of it like mirroring with a witness - but still a bit different. It may solve the issue you're having of the databases both showing as secondary replicas upon start/failover.

Comment: OK, configuration only replicas sounds like a good thing. I did notice that the documentation has configuration replicas under the linux branch. Does this mean they are not applicable to Windows only replicas; i.e. no linux replicas at all. It does not seem to be an option using SSMS, although I have not tried scripting it yet.